# Offline Folders, and Redirected Folders - Laptop cannot start up when disconnected from the network

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-xp, group-policy, offline-files

I have rolled out Redirected Folders to a number of users to test, and everything seemed fine, until I noticed a laptop that was not connected to the network attempting to log on, and everything froze up.

I am assuming this is because of the lack of network connectivity, but I assumed that offline folders will take care of that, as redirected folders are suppose to be automatically available offline. How can I ensure that this is the case, so that laptop users can work in peace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem, I updated the group policy to ensure that the computer itself had offline files enabled.

Then, once this policy had applied after the next logon and logoff, everything became smoother, because now, the offline files worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Offline files just means that the configured files/folders are available offline, but doesn't configure the ability to use a machine offline.  Verify that your cached login settings are correct so that the machine will login offline.

[MS KB link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q172931/)

Comment: Credentials are cached - That has def. been the case all along, what happens, is the computer/laptop takes an incredible amount of time when starting up saying "Applying Computer Settings" then after the log in, takes another incredible amount of time. I do believe that these are related to conflicted GPs so, I'm going to create a OU that is outside the scope of the rest of the policies, and create some new policies that do just what I need them to.

Comment: On the offline files config tab, there are two settings "Synchronize all offline files when logging on" and "Synchronize all offline files before logging off".  It sounds like unchecking (if checked) "Synchronize all offline files when logging on" may help.  In our environement with roaming profles and offline files where the CSC contains 5000+ files will take 6-10min to login.

Comment: For the prelogin lag look at your network config, maybe the machine is hanging on attempting to see the domain when offline?

Comment: edusysadmin - I'm 100% sure that the client machine is looking for something on the domain, even though it knows it's offline? The same group policy applied to other laptops works flawlessly, so you can imagine how baffled I am.

Comment: If the notebook has a hardware switch to turn off the wireless, try turning it off.  I've seen issues where the PC belives it can get a valid connection over wifi increasing lag when logging in.